# Don't load third-party code -JS -Bing Maps -Lighthouse

Tags: javascript, css, request, bing-maps, lighthouse

Problem: Bing maps API I'm using for my assignment loads unused css and scripts that significantly lower my lighthouse scores.

How can I not load third party code (Bing Ads for example) when I'm fetching the maps to display on my page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP). Whitelist allowed domains. The rest will get blocked by the browsers.

Comment: Whitelist won't help me much here as with bing maps api there's loads of scripts that are required, and then there's the ones that are not which I want to block to improve my lighthouse scores.

Comment: I thought the ads are loaded from other domains :/ Then writing a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) might do the trick. With a service worker you have absolute control over which URL gets downloaded and which are blocked.